# Finding time spent by data outside a bin in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following graph:
[image]

x-axis represents time and both x and y axis data are discrete. I want to find the time spent by the graph during the time it exits the bin marked by yellow and red lines and when it comes back. The problem is that x axis data is discrete and and I want the duration x(t') - x(t).

Suppose the graph cuts yellow line at say n= 3.2 and goes outside the bin and then again cuts the yellow line at say n = 5.1, then I want the duration (5.1-3.2). SImilarly for the red line as well. Any idea on how can I do that?

The MATLAB code to generate the data set is:

```
mu =4;
x(1)=0.2; % x_{0}
nn=1:1001;
for n=1:1000
    x(n+1) = mu*x(n)*(1-x(n));
end
figure;
plot(nn,x);
hold on;
plot([1 1010],[0.49 0.49]);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('x_{n}');
title('Plot of the equation: x_{n+1} = 4x_{n}(1-x_{n}) for x_{0} = 0.2 with 
a bin of width 0.01 from x_{n} = 0.49 to x_{n+1}= 0.50');
hold on;
plot([1 1010],[0.50 0.50]);
```

Comment: It would be great to have a sample dataset here...

Comment: Can you edit your question instead of putting the code in the comments?

Comment: Do you need to interpolate the exact time that the curve enters/leaves the band of interest? Like, maybe the blue curve is outside the band at n=3.2 but is inside at n=3.3, so it crossed the threshold of the band sometime between 3.2 and 3.3. Would you want to interpolate the find exactly when the crossing happened? Or is your time grid finely-enough sampled that you can just start at 3.3?

Comment: If I could interpolate the crossing time, then it will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I hope i interpreted this correctly when answering. So you're looking for values of n where they are x_n are 0.5 and 0.49. this will take two matrices and a while or for loop that will go for the 1000 iterations. Inside that put two if statements one for 0.5 and one for 0.49. Inside each one set a matrix to store the n value

Comment: I want the time interval between going out of the bin and then coming back, the problem is I have only discrete data points. I want to interpolate the point where the graph is touching .49 or .50.